# Making Linux program working for the next 50 years?

Tags: linux, python, qt

I have a program running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which is EOL in 2 months. The program is a Python 2 app using QT4. It works perfectly and I want to move it to Ubuntu 20. Not so fast, both Python2 and QT4 are no longer officially supported. OK, I could use some non-official repositories and probably manage to install those missing bits. But in 2025 (end of support for Ubuntu 20) I will be in the same situation, and installing outdated libraries will be even worse.

Due to the nature of the program its content will never expire, and I want to be able to use it in the next 50 years. I've always believed in open source, but now I can see that having access to the source code is not everything. The author will most likely not convert it to Python3/QT5 (no updates from him in the last 4 years), but even if he did, that's not a real solution, as QT5 and Python3 will stop being supported one day.

I've tried compiling python to binary using two different methods. It somewhat works, but the program starts awfully slow (30 secs) compared to 1 second when running as python2 app. Besides, will such compiled binaries (using Ubuntu 16) work on all next LTS editions of Ubuntu for many decades to come (glibc dependencies, etc.)?

I would appreciate some creative ideas how to approach this issue, thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119500/discussion-on-question-by-filipo-making-linux-program-working-for-the-next-50-ye).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I worked with a company that had this kind of requirement they were interested in more like 100 years.  To be honest by the difference between 50 and 100 years doesn't seem that much.  Any bets on the what the future will look like are going to be wrong.  So I'd be very skeptical about any advice telling you *this* or *that* will still be around.

The company I was working with was much more interested in whether the content they had created would be accessible / available to people to read in 100 years from now.  To that end they they pretty much accepted that they couldn't have any software that still worked over that time frame.

Instead the focus was much more about make the file formats human readable, well documented, open and if possible self explanatory.

For them this resulted in them storing everything in an open XML standard, and only using SQL databases as a secondary index.  There was an acceptance by them that the software was going to change over time, but at least they could control the file format meaning there was always a way to get new software to be compatible.

---

When it comes to keeping software alive, web-based software GUIs have survived a little better than anything that's tied to one specific desktop environment or platform library.  HTML started in 1993 and despite many changes, has remained backward compatible with its simplest features.

If you are going to port your software now, then porting it to a web-based option might be better.

But it really is impossible to predict what will survive.  I mean [who remembers fortran?](http://www.moreisdifferent.com/2015/07/16/why-physicsts-still-use-fortran/)

---

When software get's really old (and the oldest I've supported was ~ 20 years).  The last resort is to just accept you can't upgrade (ever again) and try to keep the physical box it's running on alive for as long as possible.  This is a surprisingly common tactic in some industries (see "[Why today's spacecraft still run on 1990s processors](https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-todays-spacecraft-still-run-on-1990s-processors/)").

As Muru points out in comment's setting this up in a VM sooner rather than later is worthwhile.  Not so long ago I saw one such "black box server" have a hard-disk failure and it was over a year to try to get another box stood up to run ancient versions of linux.

Also remember that security may be a problem.  With no ability to patch the software for security holes you will need to keep it neatly fire-walled incase there is another [heartbleed](https://heartbleed.com/).

---

But ultimately you've already found the main problem.  Libraries lose support.  Operating systems often go incompatible with old compiled librares.  Eventually [CPUs reach their end of life](https://serverfault.com/a/285211/94158) and there's no guarantee you will be able to get replacements.

Comment: Thanks, good point about the content, because this application is content oriented, and the content is definitely the most valuable piece (although not coded as easily as XML). 

But the nicely designed visual interface has also its value, and that's why I like this piece of software so much. I would be very hard to mimic that behavior using pure HTML or even adding JS. Which means I would have to use some GUI toolkit, which means at some point it would go out of support.

About the net, it will not be necessary, the application works 100% offline.

Comment: And don't forget raspberry Pi, you could purchase a couple, and access remotely?